# How many seconds of Longstaff Schwartz would it take to get machine accuracy?

Tags: options, time

Roughly speaking, using a standard programming language, a standard computer, and a standard implementation, how many seconds would it take to price an American put option to 10+ digits of accuracy in Black Scholes model?

Comment: I don’t think anyone has needs so many digits. Without looking, I believe it would depend on the option being priced.

Answer (score 1):

I've already built an LS american options pricer using C++ and I can tell that you will never have a precision of 10+ digits. It's due to the non-perfect randomness of uniform samples generated by the machine.